# System.Linq.Dynamic: How to declare an array for .Contains?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dynamic-linq

I am trying to do a simple SQL `where field in (2,3,4)` with Dynamic Linq.
kahanu's rehosted [Microsoft Dynamic Linq Library](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/blob/master/Src/System.Linq.Dynamic/DynamicLinq.cs) has a `.Contains()` that you can use in Linq like this:

```
var results = myTable.Where("@0.Contains(outerIt.abc)", new int[] { 2, 3, 4});
```

How would you remove the array parameter and specify the array in the string?
  Something like this but actually works?

```
var results = myTable.Where("[2,3,4].Contains(outerIt.abc)");
```

I looked through his [Microsoft documentation](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions) but it doesn't explain the `.Contains()`  All the documentation I've found on the Internet only refers to creating an array and passing it as a parameter like the first example above, but I found nothing on how to do the second example with just strings.

Comment: You can't. Unless you add that functionality to the parser in the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

When using [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) you can don something like:

```
var intList = new[] { 2, 3, 4 };
var results = myTable.Where("@0.Contains(outerIt.abc)", intList);
```

Comment: I need to use Contains over the Column name  like this : `data.Where("@0.Any(Name.Contains(it))", intList);` but it does not work. can you please say what's the correct way for this?